# Bootstrap Mobile Menu Issue

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a website at: https://www.romaheritage.co.uk

The issue is the Bootstrap menu at the top of the page; it works fine on desktop PCs/Laptops, but when viewed on mobile devices (phones/tablets) the two drop-down menu options "Records" & "Misc" won't expand out (at least on Android they won't, not sure about IOS because I can't test it). I think I'm overlooking something which may be obvious to others.

Can anyone view the source for the page and point me in the direction of what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work by replacing the a.dropdown-toggle by a div.dropdown-toggle.

The css is not good then but I believe you can make this right.

Here's the code

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="tb-nav-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="http://www.romaheritage.co.uk/#about">About</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">

             <!-- Change a to div -->
            <div class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Records <span class="caret"></span></div>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="http://www.romaheritage.co.uk/parish-records">BMD</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://www.romaheritage.co.uk/census-records">Census</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="http://www.romaheritage.co.uk/newspaper-articles">Newspapers</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="http://www.romaheritage.co.uk/#blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">

          <!-- Change a to div -->
          <div class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Misc. <span class="caret"></span></div>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="http://www.romaheritage.co.uk/queen-victorias-journals">Queen Victorias Journals</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="http://www.romaheritage.co.uk/#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
$("li.dropdown").click(function(e){
  $(this).toggleClass("open");
});
```